GuzzleHttp How to create an asynchronous request
I've been trying to create an async request for a few days now, and I'm not succeeding either..I don't want to wait for the response from the request, I send the request and the code continues to the front this is my code
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
$client= new Client();
$url="https://test.com?imei=123456789";
$request= new Request("GET", $url);

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->detach();

$promise->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});

//$promise->wait();

echo "Continuing with other code...\n";
die;

My composer.json
{
    "name": "findy/findy",
    "description": "A brief description of your project",
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "GuzzleHttp\\": "vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}

When I run the code I get this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::detach()
Please help me

->sendAsync() returns a GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface which does not contain a detach() method. That's why you are getting this error.

What change should I make so that the code works when the request is sent without waiting for a response, the response is not important to me

Well, Guzzle async does not really mean asynchronous.. see this as a reference > https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429#issuecomment-197152914

This is not JS, you cannot do taht in PHP. Closets thing will be to use message handler and some queue like RabbitMQ, delegate to make request and continue with stuff.

I mean you can always do something like shell_exec('php myotherscript.php &') to sort of "fire and forget" a php script if that helps
